# Vector、ポインタの使い方について

Tags: c++

以下のように出力したいのですが、うまくいきません。
宜しくお願い致します。

Example Output 1:

二つの種類の数字を1から10までで選択してください
入力）1 2
二つのフレーズが一致しません
最初のフレーズは "小島よしお"

Example Output 2:
二つの種類の数字を1から10選択してください
入力）4 9
あなたはペアを見つけました！
二つのフレーズは "田中夫妻"

//ここからコード

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> phrases;
    phrases.push_back("足利義視");
    phrases.push_back("小島よしお");
    phrases.push_back("犬神家");
    phrases.push_back("田中夫妻");
    phrases.push_back("農村");

    vector<string*> randomPhrases;
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(1));
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(4));
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(0));
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(3));
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(4));
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(2));
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(1));
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(2));
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(3));
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(0));


    // Ask user to select two phrases
    cout <<"二つの種類の数字を1から10までで選択してください"<< endl;
    int x;
    int y;
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;


    // Determine if the two selected phrases match (i.e. have the same memory address)


    if(&phrases.at(x) == &phrases.at(y))

    {
        cout <<"あなたはペアを見つけました！" << endl;
        cout << "二つのフレーズは" <<&phrases.at(x) << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<"二つのフレーズが一致しません" << endl;
        cout << "最初のフレーズは" <<&phrases.at(x) << endl;


    }





    return 0;
}
```

Comment: まず、そもそも、なぜ二つの数字は1から10の範囲なのですか？（0から9ではなくて） 、それと、なぜ `vector<string>` ではなく、 `vector<string*>` にしたのですか？

Answer (score 1):

気づいた点が四つあります。

1. `string` を使うときは `#include <string>` が必要
2. ユーザーの入力は1から10だが、`vector` のインデックスは0から始まるので、変換が必要
3. 問題が入っているのは `phrases` ではなく `randomePhrases`
4. ポインタの中身を参照するには、`&` ではなく `*` を使用

元のコードをなるべく変えないように変更すると

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>    // 1. includeが必要
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> phrases;
    phrases.push_back("足利義視");
    phrases.push_back("小島よしお");
    phrases.push_back("犬神家");
    phrases.push_back("田中夫妻");
    phrases.push_back("農村");

    vector<string*> randomPhrases;
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(1));
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(4));
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(0));
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(3));
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(4));
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(2));
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(1));
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(2));
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(3));
    randomPhrases.push_back(&phrases.at(0));


    // Ask user to select two phrases
    cout <<"二つの種類の数字を1から10までで選択してください"<< endl;
    int x;
    int y;
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    --x; --y;    // 2. インデックス変換


    // Determine if the two selected phrases match (i.e. have the same memory address)


    if(*randomPhrases.at(x) == *randomPhrases.at(y))    // 3. と 4.

    {
        cout <<"あなたはペアを見つけました！" << endl;
        cout << "二つのフレーズは" <<*randomPhrases.at(x) << endl;    // 3. と 4.
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<"二つのフレーズが一致しません" << endl;
        cout << "最初のフレーズは" <<*randomPhrases.at(x) << endl;    // 3. と 4.


    }





    return 0;
}
```

とりあえずは、これで動きます。